# .Htaccess from ?p=activate&id=57A5dz into users/activate/id/57A5dz

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to rewrite my urls from **http://www.domain.com/index.php?p=activate&id=57A5dz** into **http://www.domain.com/users/activate/id/57A5dz**.
I searched a lot around google but nothing worked.
I always see the 404 page..

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ \?p=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ ?page=$1&id=$2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/web-gallery/images/

RewriteRule ^images/(.+)$ /web-gallery/images/$1
```

And i also tried to add this:

`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/.*$ $1&id=$2 [L]`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First let's take a closer look at your rules to understand what they do.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ \?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

If the requested url is not a directory *and* the requested file is not a file *and* it the part behind the hostname and before the query string matches `^(.*)$`, internally rewrite it to whatever it was and append `p=` + whatever was matched to the query string. A request to `example.com/cookies?are=evil` would be rewritten to `example.com/cookies?are=evil&p=cookies`.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ ?page=$1&id=$2
```

If the requested url contains at least 2 path segments, internally rewrite it to the same page and replace the query string with page = everything before the last path segment & id = what is behind it.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/web-gallery/images/
RewriteRule ^images/(.+)$ /web-gallery/images/$1
```

If the requested url (or rewritten url) begins with `web-gallery/images`, rewrite `images/something` to `web-gallery/images/something`. There is however no url that matches both the condition and the first argument of rewriterule, so this rule is never, ever, executed.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/.*$ $1&id=$2 [L]
```

If the requested url has more than 2 path segments, where the first path segment doesn't contain a `/` and the second path segment contains only numbers, drop the rest of the path, and internally rewrite the url to whatever the first path segment was, followed by a & outside a query string and add id=numbers_matched to it. `http://example.com/test/1/some/thing?cookies=evil&butter=too` would be rewritten to `http://example.com/test&id=1?var=2&butter=too`.

---

To look back at what you wanted. You want the user to see `http://www.domain.com/users/activate/id/57A5dz`. This doesn't make sense to the server, so you'll have to *internally* rewrite it to let it make sense to the server. `http://www.domain.com/index.php?p=activate&id=57A5dz` should just do that. We want to match on the first url, and use those matches on the second url. The following (untested) rewriterule should do the trick for you. I hope above explanation gives you a better understanding of how these rules work.

```
RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+)/id/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?p=$1&id=$2 [L]
```